# Result Source Query Builder Invalid Request

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, query, result-source

I cannot create a result source in MySites.  Whenever I launch the Query Builder, I am greeted with the following message, even when the query box is blank.

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>
> Invalid request.

[image: In MySites > Result Sources > Query Builder]

I have activated the feature that allows the Content by Search web part to be added.

For reference, here are the URL structures:

`https//abc2-mysitestest.co.uk`

`https//abc2-test.co.uk`

Tracing the Correlation ID doesn't provide much information at all in the log files.